# Linux opens the URL after closing the java program

Tags: java, linux, url

Linux Fedora 36, GNOME 42.2, Wayland (Xorg same), Java 8 (Java 17 same)

After executing the URL opening code, the URL does not open. After closing the Java program, the URL opens on its own.

I have tried several browser open implementations, but the result is the same. I would like to know how this is solved and I'm not sure if this is a code problem and not Fedora.

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.browse(generateInteractiveUrl(httpHandler.getPort()));
```

or

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();

URI readyUrl = generateInteractiveUrl(httpHandler.getPort());

log.info("Microsoft auth URL: " + readyUrl); // returns the correct URL

d.browse(readyUrl); // opens only after closing the program О_o
```

Comment: Do `generateInteractiveUrl(httpHandler.getPort())` in advance and check that it passes before `b.browse`. Maybe it is something with threads, or missing invokeLater.

Comment: If its a code problem, then it is in `generateInteractiveUrl(httpHandler.getPort())`.

Comment: If I open the same ```stackoverflow.com``` , the problem persists. This is not related to ```generateInteractiveUrl(HttpHandler.getPort())```

Comment: What is your default browser?

Comment: Firefox, Chromuim same

Comment: I have the same issue on Alma Linux 9.1 - very annyoing!